# Angular 2 привязка данных

Tags: angular2, angular

Я пытаюсь вывести из массива ссылки с миникартинками с помощью ngFor, и есть второй фрагмент кода, который по клику на маленькую картинку должен подгрузить соответствующую ей большую(в коде переменная art1 это ссылка на картинке которая собирается в файле ts) . 
Массив миникартинок я вывел, а как передать в код параметр, который будет идентифицировать определенную картинку сообразить не могу.

```html
         <div id="imgthumb_box">
            <div *ngFor="let images of art2" >
              <a  (click)="onMini()" ><img src="assets/articles/imgmini/{{images.pathimage}}" alt="" ></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="img_box">
            <img id="img1" src="{{art1}}" alt="">
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Да я видел про индекс, но я не понял как его получить в ts. Я также нашел следующий способ на этом форуме.  Исользовать атрибут:           <div id="imgthumb_box">
              <a  *ngFor="let images of art2" [attr.data-sectionvalue]="11" (click)="onMini($event)"><img src="assets/articles/imgmini/{{images.pathimage}}" alt=""></a>
          </div> , но что-то получить значение вот так не получилось :   onMini(event) {
    this.link = event.target.dataset.images.pathimage;;
  }

Answer (score 0):

Переписываете сигнатуру метода `onMini()` таким образом `onMini(index : number)` так вы сможете получить доступ к индексу изображения по которому совершен клик.

```html
         <div id="imgthumb_box">
            <div *ngFor="let images of art2; index as i" >
              <a  (click)="onMini(i)" ><img src="assets/articles/imgmini/{{images.pathimage}}" alt="" ></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="img_box">
            <img id="img1" src="{{art1}}" alt="">
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает)